# The form of the wave function in time-dependent perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, perturbation-theory

I'm trying to understand why the wave function is expressed as follows in a time dependent perturbation.

[image: me e]
I understand that since the $c(t)$ are unspecified functions, it is mathematically reasonable to just factor out the exponential part, and that it helps get the differential equation for $c(t)$ be expressed in quantities we already know. The part that I'm confused by is the physical motivation. Since the the original eigenstates are no longer the eigenstates of the full Hamiltonian, why does it make sense to specify their independent time evolution? And also is it reasonable to think of the time evolution as the time dependence of the original Hamiltonian, modulated by the perturbation? In that case, it still doesn't make sense because the functions are still not eigenstates. I do understand the perturbation analysis carried out afterwards, just need to wrap my head around the motivation for this expression.

Comment: I mean, you don't need the complex exponentials there. You can redefine the time-dependent coefficients to absorb them. It just turns out to be a convenient thing to do in the derivation. Physically, you're factoring out the time-dependence due to the free evolution of the state under the unperturbed Hamiltonian, and what's *left* is due to the perturbing Hamiltonian, but you don't have to do this.

Comment: [Dirac's point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)#Time-dependent_perturbation_theory) is that for vanishing perturbation, this way the *c* s are constants. You want to decouple the predictable parts of the problem from the unknown ones. Do a simple example.

Comment: I get that we're factoring out the dependence due to the free evolution of the state in the unperturbed Hamiltonian, and the rest of the time-dependence is due to the perturbing Hamiltonian. My issue is that neither of the states would evolve that way, because they're not eigenstates of the Hamiltonian anymore.

Comment: Yes, that is the *very point* of perturbation theory: expanding in terms of somebody else's eigenstates.... Are you *unequivocally cool* with the interaction picture?